# In Google Sheets, can you repeatedly autofill until next non-blank cell all at once? (previous value)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Basically, what I want to do is fill all of the blank cell in a column with the value of the previous non-blank cells. For example:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to do this without having to do the auto-fill individually for each set of cells with the same value, as I have a sheet that's thousands of entries long.

Update:
I did not elaborate fully on what I'm looking to achieve, and I'm sorry for that.
Here is a link to a test file:
[Test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cg6GwKXxeQifHAs9Tm2jPmjPq_2g_vrKk7qnddsyqT8/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a script adding a new row each day, (not in the file). I want to have a array formula similar to:
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLookup(Row(B2:B), {IF(B2:B="",,Row(B2:B)),B2:B},2,1))

Unfortunately, the above formula chooses the value from the above cell, not below. I hope I have clarified my desired achievement better now.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Marcus!

Yes, this is the way. First go to **File-Settings-Calculations** tab and enable **Iterative calculation**.

Now in cell **C2** write the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A="",$C$1:$C,$A$2:$A))`

Copy the result and with **Ctrl+Shift+V** (*Editing - Paste Special - Values ​​only*) replace the original column A. Now you can clear **C2** and return **Iterative calculation** to **OFF**

**Update** To fill cells in column fro bottom to top type to **E2** formula

`=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(B2),OFFSET($B$1,MIN(IF(ISBLANK(B3:B),"",ROW(B3:B)))-1,0),B2)),"")`

and press Ctrl+Enter to Autofill

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! 

I did not elaborate fully on what I'm looking to achieve, and I'm sorry for that. 

Here is like to a test file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cg6GwKXxeQifHAs9Tm2jPmjPq_2g_vrKk7qnddsyqT8/edit?usp=sharing

I have a script adding a new row each day, (not in the file). I want to have a array formula similar to :
ARRAYFORMULA(VLookup(Row(B2:B), {IF(B2:B="",,Row(B2:B)),B2:B},2,1))

Unfortunately, the above formula chooses the value from the above cell, not below. I hope I have clarified my desired achievement better now.

Comment: @Marcus Oh, you mean fill from bottom to top? I have changed my answer

Comment: your updated solution also worked. Thank you for your time and effort. I'm going with doubleunary solution since it filled the entire column. It's more convenient in my make.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `map()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=map( 
  B2:B14, 
  lambda( 
    cell, 
    if( 
      len(cell), 
      cell, 
      iferror(+filter(cell:B14, len(cell:B14), row(cell:B14) > row(cell))) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cg6GwKXxeQifHAs9Tm2jPmjPq_2g_vrKk7qnddsyqT8/edit#gid=1390620047).

Comment: Thanks a bunch @doubleunary, that worked like a treat! 
I do not really know what this formula does, but I managed to make it work in my sheet:D